# Выполнение запроса с комментариями в firebird

Tags: c#, firebird

Столкнулся с неожиданной проблемой. В запросе используются комментарии строк (--comment), ранее встречал только комментарии блоков (/*comment*/)

Текст запросов помещен в текстовые файлы и в последующем считывается, вносится в FBCommand.CommandText и выполняется.

Так вот: считывается запрос корректно, запрос разбит на строки и отформатирован так, как расположен в текстовом файле. Но как только я его вношу в FBCommand, разбиение на строки пропадает, и все выливается в одну длинную строку без переносов строк. Соответственно запрос становится не валидным, так как после первого же коммента отсекается весь хвост запроса.

Я понимаю, что можно строковые комменты заменить на блочные, но хотелось бы разобраться в чем подвох и почему fbcommand исправляет форматирование запроса на какое-то свое. Может есть какой-то флаг, о котором я ничего не знаю?

Например:

```
select
    field1,
--    field2,
    field3
from mytable
```

Такое запрос не выполнится, так как все после field1, будет закомментировано и запрос станет невалидным:

```
select       field1,    --    field2,        field3    from mytable
```

В вот такой запрос выполнится, даже, если станет одной строкой

```
select
    field1,
/*    field2,*/
    field3
from mytable

select        field1,    /*    field2,*/        field3    from mytable
```

Заранее благодарен за подсказки и помощь в решении данной проблемы

PS: Использую для выполнения запросов модуль .net FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient

Comment: Варианта тут три: 1. "Ручной" через split и indexof, и, пожалуй 2. через регулярку. Вы хотите сделать замену регуляркой?  3. Можно схитрить, заменить `--` на `/*`, а возврат каретки на `/**/`, плюс то же в конец sql (для FB такое катит, но не все SQL такое хавают, mssql не ест) тогда с `/*` по `/**/` будет комментарием.

Comment: Плюс, есть случай когда `--` может встречаться в строковых литералах. Тогда прийдётся "перекомпиляцию делать"

Comment: @nick_n_a да переделать комменты можно и руками, благо таких запросов штук 5. Больше интересует что я делаю не так или это бага в провайдере или это они намеренно делают, но я просто не понимаю зачем.

Comment: Ищите проблему в коде, который читает файл в строку. В нескольких приложениях использую хранение sql в xml-файлах, таких проблем не было

Comment: Странно так не должно быть, попробуйте другой провайдер, скачайте с официального сайта, можете даже с исходниками тут https://www.firebirdsql.org/en/additional-downloads/ так же внимательно посмотрите ваши исходники, может у вас вкралась ошибка (например, я столкнулся, выборка хранится в xml-формате а при вставке "плохим" редактором теряется возврат каретки или что-то подобное; VCL иногда теряет возврат каретки)

Comment: @Андрей, после прочтения текст в переменной разбит на строки. Именно после пересвоения в commandtext лежат данные без разбития на строки.

Comment: @pincher1519, хм, а попробуйте sql не в commandtext помещать, а при создании FbCommand передавать в качестве параметра, я именно так делаю

Comment: Спасибо всем, оказалось, что кодировки строк разные... Проблема оказалась от туда, откуда ее и не ждал.

Comment: Граждане, удаливший мой ответ. Я дал исчерпывающий ответ на свой вопрос. Проблема была в "пересвоении строк" в команду "CommandText".  Строки были разных кодировок "Win1251" и "Unicode" В следствии чего неверно интерпретировались перевод каретки и новая строка. Зачем удалили мой ответ на мой вопрос?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо всем, оказалось, что кодировки строк разные... Проблема оказалась от туда, откуда ее и не ждал.

Запрос сливался просто в одну строку, из-за того, что перевод строк в разных кодировках может оказаться разный. После установки правильной кодировки текста запроса проблема отпала.